# Can not mount overlayfs inside initrd

Tags: kernel, initramfs, overlayfs

I am trying to use read-only overlayfs(no workdir and upperdir) inside custom initrd.

This works fine in completely booted OS:

```
mkdir /tmp/ovl1 /tmp/ovl2 /tmp/merged
mount -t overlay none -o lowerdir=/tmp/ovl1:/tmp/ovl2 /tmp/merged
```

This also works if I use `busybox sh` as shell, which has built-in mount command.

Inside initrd shell directories are successfully created, and mount command gives this error:

```
mount: mounting none on /tmp/merged failed: No such device
```

Here is output of mount command inside initrd:

```
rootfs on / type rootfs (...
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (...
proc on /proc type proc (...
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (...
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (...
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (...
```

I got no idea how to debug this one :(

P.S. Now I use AUFS and it works fine, but it was rejected from mainline kernel and it's recommended to switch to overlayfs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was sure, that module is statically compiled in kernel, but I was wrong: `CONFIG_OVERLAY_FS=m`.
After adding the `overlay` module to initrd everything works fine.